# Find a text (C21) from Sheet2 in Sheet1 and then copy a fixed range from Sheet2 into the next cell where text was found in Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning-while-doing macros, I am new with this so thank you very much for your help :)

I am trying to create a macro that:

1. reads a text in one cell in Sheet2 (cell C21)
2. looks for it in Sheet 1 (column C)
3. copy a fixed range in Sheet2 (D26:P26)
4. Paste the info from the next cell where the text was found in Sheet 1 (so if for example in #2 the text was found in the cell C23...the copied info is paste from D23 on)
5. refresh a pivot table in Sheet2
6. refresh a graph on Sheet2

Sheet 1= TRY Data

Sheet 2= TRY graph

This is the macro I  have came up until now...finds the text, nows where it is but does not paste the info (and does not have how to update the graph). Once again thank you very much! :)

```
Sub Save2()

    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = Worksheets("TRY graph").Range("C21").Value & " C-2018"

    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("TRY Data").Range("C:C").Find(strSearch, >lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

       Worksheets("TRY graph").Range("D26:P26").Copy

       Worksheets("TRY Data").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial >xlPasteValues
    Else

       MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
    End If

    Dim pivotTable As pivotTable

    pivotTable.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have not actually asked any question here. And its better to focus a question to *one specific issue*, not several.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment...the question is (in other words): how to fix the code in order to be able to copy the range  D26:P26 from Sheet2 and paste it in the next cell where the text in C21 from Sheet2 was found. Thanks again! /// I think my mistake is in this line: Worksheets("TRY Data").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @Nikolaos Polygenis, thank you for answering so quickly :) however the range is not pasted in the next column where the cell with the matching text is...right now the range is pasted in the following column where the active cell is...and that cell can be anywhere I click before running the macro. Please help :(

Comment: **Try replacing** `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` **with** `Range("D" & rng1.row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` **or whatever column you want to use.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try:( I add you code in comment for the pivot.. workbook_pivot_exists is the workbook where your pivot is)

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Save2()
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = Worksheets("TRY graph").Range("C21").Value & " C-2018"

    Dim rng1 As Range

    Dim adrs As String

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("TRY Data").Range("C:C").Find(strSearch, lookat:=xlPart)



    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

    adrs = rng1.Address

    Sheets("TRY graph").Range("D26:P26").Copy


    With Sheets("TRY Data")



     .Range(adrs).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    End With

    Else

        MsgBox strSearch & " not found"

    End If

Dim pivotTable As pivotTable

'to refresh your pivot try:
'Set pivotTable = whorkbook_pivot_exists.PivotTables("myPivot")


'pivotTable.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: @Nikolaos Polygenis, thank you for answering so quickly :) however the range is not pasted in the next column where the cell with the matching text is...right now the range is pasted in the following column where the active cell is...and that cell can be anywhere I click before running the macro. Please help :( – L.B. 15 hours ago......

ok i didnt understand that you want this please wait ..